# How to make a random string generator that doesn't repeat strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, generator

I am developing a "Never Have I Ever" webpage that generates Never Have I Ever scenarios everytime the user clicks a button.

I have the generator made, but the issue I am now faced with is that the generator keeps repeating the same strings after a few clicks.

Is there any way that would randomise what string has been picked but then not pick that string again?

```
 var scenario = [
    'Never Have I Ever 1',
    'Never Have I Ever 2',
    'Never Have I Ever 3',
    'Never Have I Ever 4',
    'Never Have I Ever 5',
    'Never Have I Ever 6',
    'Never Have I Ever 7',
    'Never Have I Ever 8',
    'Never Have I Ever 9',
    'Never Have I Ever 10',
    'Never Have I Ever 11',
    'Never Have I Ever 12',
    'Never Have I Ever 13',
    'Never Have I Ever 14',
    'Never Have I Ever 15',
    'Never Have I Ever 16',
    'Never Have I Ever 17',
    'Never Have I Ever 18'
]

function generate() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scenario.length));
    document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML = scenario[randomNumber];
}
```

Comment: You can shuffle the array when your game first starts up, and then `.pop()` a string whenever you want to get a new scenario (maybe push it back into the beginning of the array so you can cycle through scenarios perhaps)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which removes an item by index based on the selected `randomNumber` from your array after presenting:

```js
 let scenario = ['Never Have I Ever 1', 'Never Have I Ever 2', 'Never Have I Ever 3', 'Never Have I Ever 4', 'Never Have I Ever 5', 'Never Have I Ever 6', 'Never Have I Ever 7', 'Never Have I Ever 8', 'Never Have I Ever 9', 'Never Have I Ever 10', 'Never Have I Ever 11', 'Never Have I Ever 12', 'Never Have I Ever 13', 'Never Have I Ever 14', 'Never Have I Ever 15', 'Never Have I Ever 16', 'Never Have I Ever 17', 'Never Have I Ever 18'];

function generate() {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scenario.length));
    let sentence = 'No more sentences';

    if (scenario.length > 0) {
       sentence = 
scenario[randomNumber];
       scenario = scenario.filter((e, i) => i !== randomNumber);
       console.log('length of remaining scenario items:', scenario.length);
    }

    document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML = sentence;
}

generate();
```

```html
<div id="sentence"></div>
<button onclick="generate()">Generate new sentence</button>
```

Probably you can add extra checking if you don't have more items in the array.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generator function, which creates `copy of quotes` and return a `closure function`. On every call, get the random `number`, remove that `element` form copy.

```js
function generate(scenario) {
  let copy = [...scenario];
  return function () {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    const data = copy[randomNumber];
    copy.splice(randomNumber, 1);
    return data;
  };
}

const quotePre = document.getElementById("random-quote");
const scenario = ["Never Have I Ever 1","Never Have I Ever 2","Never Have I Ever 3","Never Have I Ever 4","Never Have I Ever 5","Never Have I Ever 6","Never Have I Ever 7","Never Have I Ever 8","Never Have I Ever 9","Never Have I Ever 10","Never Have I Ever 11","Never Have I Ever 12","Never Have I Ever 13","Never Have I Ever 14","Never Have I Ever 15","Never Have I Ever 16","Never Have I Ever 17","Never Have I Ever 18"];

const randomGenerator = generate(scenario);
setInterval(function () {
  const quote = randomGenerator();
  if (quote) quotePre.innerText = quote;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<pre id="random-quote"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by maintaining a hash object. Where you keep the index values which are already been displayed and generate random index until a unique index value is not generated.

```js
 let scenario = ['Never Have I Ever 1', 'Never Have I Ever 2', 'Never Have I Ever 3', 'Never Have I Ever 4', 'Never Have I Ever 5', 'Never Have I Ever 6', 'Never Have I Ever 7', 'Never Have I Ever 8', 'Never Have I Ever 9', 'Never Have I Ever 10', 'Never Have I Ever 11', 'Never Have I Ever 12', 'Never Have I Ever 13', 'Never Have I Ever 14', 'Never Have I Ever 15', 'Never Have I Ever 16', 'Never Have I Ever 17', 'Never Have I Ever 18'];

const btn = document.querySelector('#generator');
const display = document.querySelector('#display');
let hash = {};
let clickCount = 0;

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  const {length} = scenario;
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
  
  while (hash[randomIndex] !== undefined) {
   randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
  }
  
 if (clickCount > length) {
   hash = {};
    alert('Added all strings');
  }
  
  hash[randomIndex] = 1;
  display.innerText += scenario[randomIndex] + "\n";
  clickCount++;
});
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
<button id="generator">Generate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is to shuffle the array and [pop](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp) from it. That way the value isn't available for the next iteration. [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) makes common randomness stuff like this simple, so I used it in this answer.

```js
//define scenarios
var scenarios = ['Never Have I Ever 1', 'Never Have I Ever 2', 'Never Have I Ever 3'];

//make a shuffled copy of scenarios
var shuffledScenarios = randoSequence(scenarios);

function generate(){
  //refill the shuffled array if needed
  if(shuffledScenarios.length == 0) shuffledScenarios = randoSequence(scenarios);
  
  //remove a value from the shuffled array and output it
  console.log(shuffledScenarios.pop().value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
<button onclick="generate()">Show the next one</button>
```

Like I said, this answer uses randojs, so if you want to use this answer, just make sure you include this in the head tag of your HTML document near the top:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

If you have any questions, leave me a comment!